# mongo add field to document ($set doesn't)

Tags: php, mongodb

What I want:

- fetch some documents
- for every document, set a field:
- - change it, if it exists
- - add it, if it doesn't

What I do:

```
// fresh data
print_r(iterator_to_array($collection->find()->limit(2)));

// query
$docs = $collection->find()->limit(2);
// fetch
foreach ( $docs AS $id => $doc ) {
  // update
  $collection->update(array('_id' => $doc['_id']), array(
    '$set' => array(
      'existing_field' => 'x',
      'new_field' => 'y',
    ),
  ), array('multiple' => false));
}

// verify
print_r(iterator_to_array($collection->find()->limit(2)));
```

Why doesn't that do anything? The existing field isn't changed and the new field isn't added. Is the condition maybe wrong??

PS. The full code (with a lot of junk in between): http://pastebin.com/CNfCVxex
lines 33 - 37 -- fresh data
lines 63 - 76 -- query, fetch & update
lines 79 - 80 -- verify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with the driver you are using here, but from your description you can achieve what you want in a single database hit, no need to fetch/loop/update..

The $set operator will insert or update a field depending on whether it exists or not.

```
db.Collection.update({}, { $set : { "myfield" : "x" } }, false, true)
```

The above would set the 'myfield' field in all documents in the collection to 'x', or if it already exists it would change the value to 'x'. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm using PHP. Can't update all at once, because the updates are different. I would think the `$set` would do what I want, but for some reason it doesn't: no change. Your example also doesn't include the `limit(2)` btw.

Comment: You can set two fields with $set. I don't think I really understand what you're trying to achieve. You're trying to set field 'a' if field 'a' exists, and if not set field 'b' so the document won't contain 'a'?

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly that, but it won't work. If I pass the update object without the `$set` (`{"existing_field": "x", "new_field": "y"}`) the whole document is updated (and replaced, like the specs say it should. If I use `$set`, nothing happens! Pf?

Comment: Using `{ $set { "existing_field" : "x", "new_field" : "y" } }` should work fine, I do it all the time, although it will set both fields in all documents whether they exist or not. Perhaps as Hightechrider suggests it's because of the additional array?

Comment: Related to this, my `$set` wouldn't work once because I was doing `{new_field: 'y'}`. It's important to have the key as a string like `{'new_field': 'y'}`. Just a little JavaScript semantics issue someone might run into.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to convert the string `$doc['_id']` back to a MongoId by using `new MongoId`.  See the example at the bottom of this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php

Comment: `$doc['_id'] instanceof MongoId`, not a string. I dont think `new MongoId($row['_id']->{'$id'})` is necessary. (I've tried and it doesn't matter.) Without `$set`, the document updates (but is replaced completely). So the condition works.

Comment: Turn verbose logging on and take a look at what's actually being passed to MongoDB.

Comment: Your update also appears to have an extra Array wrapped around the $set command, why is that?  Wouldn't that make the update document `{{$set:{'existing_field':'x','new_field':'y'}}` ?

Comment: The extra array was a typo (in the post, not the code). Fixed it. How do I turn on verbose logging (on Ubuntu) and where do I see the logs?

Comment: Fire up the Mongo shell and use `db.adminCommand({setParameter:1, logLevel:4})`  Command line options to set logging location are here:- http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Logging#Logging-CommandLineOptions